# Schema Search - Oracle Developer Tools v21.5.0 for VS Code

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to use Oracle Developer Tools (v21.5.0) to search the connected schema for a table/object/view/column without initiating a query? For example, I want to know if the column "EmployeeName" exists anywhere in a database schema.

I tried searching from the sidebar which is partially successful. The search & filter works but only at the level displayed. This is fine if I am looking for a table or view name but not if I am searching for a column name across the entire database.

Comment: "Is it possible to use Oracle Developer Tools (v21.5.0) to search the connected schema for a table/object/view/column without initiating a query" Almost certainly not as the information is kept in Oracle's data dictionary and to get the information you need to query that data dictionary; if you don't query the data dictionary then you won't get the information. Even if you are not performing the query manually then it is certain that whatever tool you are using will implicitly generate the query to get the information.

Comment: @MT0 Maybe I am misinterpreting your response but searching the catalog of objects in an oracle db is most definitely possible. See [SQL to search objects, including stored procedures, in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853547/sql-to-search-objects-including-stored-procedures-in-oracle) for an example of a similar question asked & answered. My question was specifically about whether or not the Oracle Developer Tools extension for VS Code can search the objects in the schema for a string.

Comment: That link shows you how to do it with a query. My point was that it is probably impossible to do it "without initiating a query" (which is what the question asks); and even if you click various bits of the tooling and it provides you the information then the tooling is going to be performing the same (or similar) queries so you still won't be doing it "without initiating a query".

Comment: This isn't possible, but I will add it to our list of enhancements for a future release. Thank you.